# If $P(A_n) \to 1$ and $P(B_n) \to 1$, does $P(A_n \cap B_n) \to 1$?

Tags: probability

If we have to sequences of measurable sets $(A_n)$ and $(B_n)$ such that $P(A_n) \to 1$ and $P(B_n) \to 1$, does their intersection also converges to 1? That is, does $P(A_n \cap B_n) \to 1$?

Comment: $P(A_n\cap B_n) = P(A_n)-P(A_n\cap B_n^c) \geq P(A_n)-P(B_n^c)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Indeed, from $$\mathbb P(A\cup B)=\mathbb P(A)+\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(A\cap B),$$ we get $$\mathbb P(A_n\cap B_n)=\mathbb P(A_n)+\mathbb P(B_n)-\mathbb P(A_n\cup B_n)\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow } 1.$$